# how to set stack size for a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

When I create a new thread and inside  thread function allocate some memory  on heap using malloc then process memory is increased by 64 mb.Before creating the thread I tried to set the stack size to 64 kb using pthread_attr_setstacksize but there is no impact on process memory. If I create 2 threads then process memory is increased by 64*2=128 mb

Example code https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-pthread-attr-setstacksize-set-stacksize-attribute-object

Is there an solution to avoid extra 64 mb of memory for each thread?

Answer (score 1):

> Before creating the thread I tried to set the stack size to 64 kb using pthread_attr_setstacksize

That *is* the correct way to set stack size.

> but there is no impact on process memory.

It doesn't sound like your memory consumption is coming from the thread stack.

It sounds like your `malloc` implementation reserves memory in 64MiB chunks (probably to manage thread-local allocation arenas).

Accurately measuring actual memory usage on modern systems is surprisingly non-trivial. If you are looking at `VM` in `ps` output, you are doing it wrong. If you are looking at `RSS`, that's closer but still only an approximation.

> Is there an solution to avoid extra 64 mb of memory for each thread?

There *might* be environment variables or functions you can call to tune your `malloc` implementation.

But you haven't told us *which* `malloc` implementation (or OS) you are using, and without that we can't help you.

Also note that "avoiding extra 64MiB" is likely not a goal you should pursue (see http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I/m using ubuntu 16.04.                                                                                                              gcc (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026                                                                   In thread function            char* x=malloc(1); increased memory by 64 MB.